# How to get index of elements between the first and last values of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program where I take one color and compare it to other colors in an array. I use the Euclidean Color Distance formula ([wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#Euclidean)) to determine the color distance between two colors but what I am trying to do is getting the 2nd 3rd and 4th smallest values index so then I can assign that values of those indexes to the value of it being compared to. Here is what I have tried.

```
private void findUnknownColors(Color[] firstAnchor, Color[] foundAnchor){
    //Find distance between each color in first anchor and color arr

    double[] storeClosestColors = new double [24];
    //fill the array with a random value.
    Arrays.fill(storeClosestColors, 5000);

    for(int i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){
        storeClosestColors[i] = colorDistance(firstAnchor[0], colorArray[i]);
        if(i < storeClosestColors[2]){
            storeClosestColors[2] = i;
        }
    }
//get 3 closest colors disregarding 0.0
    System.out.println("Closest colors: " + Arrays.toString(storeClosestColors));   
}
```

This is the way I compare colors and how I determine the difference between one and another. It returns a float value representing its difference. The smaller the closer, the larger the farther they are on the RGB spectrum.

```
public double colorDistance(Color c1, Color c2) {
    double rmean = (c1.getRed() + c2.getRed()) / 2;
    int r = c1.getRed() - c2.getRed();
    int g = c1.getGreen() - c2.getGreen();
    int b = c1.getBlue() - c2.getBlue();
    double weightR = 2 + rmean / 256;
    double weightG = 4.0;
    double weightB = 2 + (255 - rmean) / 256;
    //System.out.println(Math.sqrt(weightR * r * r + weightG * g * g + weightB * b * b));
    return Math.sqrt(weightR * r * r + weightG * g * g + weightB * b * b);
}
```

This is the output.

```
Color array: [java.awt.Color[r=171,g=162,b=184], java.awt.Color[r=103,g=7,b=10], java.awt.Color[r=183,g=60,b=67], java.awt.Color[r=111,g=20,b=37], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=4,b=45], java.awt.Color[r=72,g=127,b=57], java.awt.Color[r=171,g=172,b=199], java.awt.Color[r=83,g=146,b=89], java.awt.Color[r=146,g=171,b=62], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=3,b=30], java.awt.Color[r=165,g=61,b=49], java.awt.Color[r=140,g=181,b=78], java.awt.Color[r=155,g=22,b=22], java.awt.Color[r=170,g=151,b=64], java.awt.Color[r=5,g=10,b=64], java.awt.Color[r=155,g=147,b=173], java.awt.Color[r=34,g=131,b=51], java.awt.Color[r=140,g=165,b=51], java.awt.Color[r=1,g=15,b=63], java.awt.Color[r=30,g=139,b=64], java.awt.Color[r=178,g=168,b=188], java.awt.Color[r=170,g=36,b=33], java.awt.Color[r=113,g=26,b=46], java.awt.Color[r=112,g=25,b=44]]
Closest colors: [271.20551190471775, 188.49519224638064, 0.0, 148.0690295098877, 304.4738994868854, 221.26990553111827, 301.1983358187757, 236.5966372330765, 230.12584023475068, 309.0199161765306, 40.283177320067495, 252.41092952514953, 112.21335008589664, 183.30020415632384, 291.59154464121553, 242.0912147311422, 273.11361532336684, 222.63613286313162, 293.7586168948921, 285.47859349476624, 283.3636066853858, 73.66764469561926, 135.36298134552888, 138.41173575152507]
```

Comment: can you show colorArray.

Comment: sure I will add it. @Omore

Comment: updated my post @Omore

Comment: Take the size of array, divide it by size of one element. This will give you the number the of elements. Divide it by 2. Thats the middle index.

Comment: I don't exactly want the middle indexes I want the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th smallest double values index as I stated in the question. @VidorVistrom

Comment: This [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/)  will be useful to you !

Comment: `what I am trying to do is getting the 2nd 3rd and 4th smallest values index` - my question is, how are you calculating the `values` of each `Color`? the way I see, each `Color` object is containing 3 `int` values - how are you making a single value from 3 `int`s for each `Color`?

Comment: Look at the `colorDistance` method for how I calculate the values between two colors.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give you some suggestions about how you can do what you want to do (according to my understanding).

- Calculate the `colorDistance` for each color of `colorArray` from color `C` (*), store the distances of each color in the same sequence as the colors of `colorArray`. Let's name the array `colorDistances`. So, `colorDistances[i] = Distance between colorArray[i] and C`.
- Copy the `colorDistances` array. Let's name the array `colorDistancesCopy`.
- Perform [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) on `colorDistancesCopy`. While doing the sort, keep a track on index changes of the elements of `colorDistancesCopy` in each step (**).
- If the previous step is done correctly, at the end of that step, you should have `colorDistancesCopy` in the sorted order, and the order of each element of the unsorted `colorDistances` array. From these info, you can easily determine the 2nd, 3rd, 4th closest color of `colorArray` from color `C`.

(*): From your codes, what I see is that the value of `C` will be from an array (`firstAnchor`). In this case, if you have to use all the values of `firstAnchor`, then you will have to follow the procedure repeatedly.

(**): To easily keep track of the index changes in each step, you will need two additional arrays - one will store the locations of the sorted elements in the unsorted array, and the other will store the order of the unsorted elements.

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem. I didn't post everything in the project but a lot of what you stated I had implemented already.

Comment: Good for you then.